# AWS NAT - multiple interfaces for networking

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb

how can we set up a LB with multiple external interfaces?
our requirement is to set up a layer7/4 lb for websites that are pointing externally, and as we have more than 30+ servers as to be hosted externally, we want a single load balancer that can cater the need of layer 7/4 load balancing for all the websites

could someone suggest me a 3rdparty load balancer, that can be hosted in EC2/AWS that has multiple external interfaces, that can do both layer 4 and layer 7 load balancing with content forwarding?

Any help or advice is appriciated.

//pasha

Comment: Check [this](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/search/results/ref=srh_navgno_search_box?page=1&searchTerms=netscaler) and [this](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/search/results/ref=srh_navgno_search_box?page=1&searchTerms=f5+big)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Netscaler VPX as EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

We deployed a Layer 4/7 Loadbalancer - "Kemp" in AWS.
The actual question was to get assistance with HAProxy, but I found the third part solutions like "Kemp", "BArracuda", "NetScalar" etc, can be used for acheiving the L4/L7 loadbalancing. 
Kemp provides more or less same functionality as most of the L7 LB available in market. 
It is available both Physical and in virtual.

Thanks,
pasha